# Append string to list directly before it in a list of lists and strings

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of lists and strings and would like to append the string elements into the list element directly before it. Below is a sample of the data.

```
data = [['way','say','may','lay'], 'wake', ['hay','pay','yay'], 'lake', ['tay'], 'shake']
```

The desire output should be something like this:

```
out = [['way','say','may','lay','wake'], ['hay','pay','yay','lake'], ['tay', 'shake']]
```

I have tried converting the list into a dataframe and use `groupby` and `cumsum()` however this seems to only partly solve my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could zip together the odd and even parts of `data` and use list addition of those parts to build your desired output:

```py
out = [odd + [even] for odd, even in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])]
```

Output:

```
[
  ['way', 'say', 'may', 'lay', 'wake'],
  ['hay', 'pay', 'yay', 'lake'],
  ['tay', 'shake']
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iterator from `data` and zip the iterator with itself to fetch two items from the iterator for each iteration:

```
seq = iter(data)
print([[*lst, item] for lst, item in zip(seq, seq)])
```

This outputs:

```
[['way', 'say', 'may', 'lay', 'wake'], ['hay', 'pay', 'yay', 'lake'], ['tay', 'shake']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always loop through the list and create your `out` list, this case even if you have multiple strings, they will be appended to the previous list:

```
data = [['way','say','may','lay'], 'wake', 'wake2', ['hay','pay','yay'], 'lake', ['tay'], 'shake']
out = []
for elem in data:
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        out.append(elem)
    elif isinstance(elem, str):
        # assuming first element is always a list
        out[-1].append(elem)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['way', 'say', 'may', 'lay', 'wake', 'wake2'], ['hay', 'pay', 'yay', 'lake'], ['tay', 'shake']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes a list `data` with  `words_collected` is an initially empty list and `result` is another empty list that will store the resulting sublists.

It combines these elements according to a logic pattern and stores the result in `result`.

The output is a list of sublists where each sublist is created by merging elements from `data` in a logic manner.

```py
data = [
    ["way", "say", "may", "lay"],
    "wake",
    ["hay", "pay", "yay"],
    "lake",
    ["tay"],
    "shake",
]
words_collected = []
result = []
for word_index in range(len(data)):
    if word_index % 2 != 0:
        words_collected.append(data[word_index])
for list_index in range(len(data)):
    if list_index % 2 == 0:
        sublist = data[list_index]
        sublist.extend([(words_collected[list_index // 2])])
        result.append(sublist)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['way', 'say', 'may', 'lay', 'wake'], ['hay', 'pay', 'yay', 'lake'], ['tay', 'shake']]
```